# Why pandas groupby adds additional (groupby_info) column into the dataframe and how to remove them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have dataframe `df_M` with 4 columns, and do group by `'protein'` and sort by `'[M]'`.

```
df_M = df_M[['protein', 'cl', 'pept', '[M]']]
df_M = df_M.groupby('protein').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, '[M]')
```

The result comes out with two additional columns in the front which are replication of `'protein'` and `index`? How to do groupby and sort without getting these columns?

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need `groupby` but `sort` by both columns by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df_M = df_M.sort_values(['protein','[M]'])
```

But if want use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) add parameter `group_keys=False`:

> **group_keys** : boolean, default **True**
>
> When calling apply, add group keys to index to identify pieces

```
df_M = df_M.groupby('protein', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, '[M]')
```

Sample:

```
df_M = pd.DataFrame({'protein':list('ababba'),
                    '[M]':[2,3,5,8,0,6],
                    'cl':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

print (df_M)
   [M]  cl protein
0    2   1       a
1    3   2       b
2    5   3       a
3    8   4       b
4    0   5       b
5    6   6       a

df_M = df_M.sort_values(['protein','[M]'])

#df_M = df_M.groupby('protein', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, '[M]')

print (df_M)
   [M]  cl protein
0    2   1       a
2    5   3       a
5    6   6       a
4    0   5       b
1    3   2       b
3    8   4       b
```